# ArgumentError: Unknown field error Ruby JSON.parse(json_string, object_class: XYZ)

Tags: json, ruby, object

My Ruby class `Routeguide::Rectangle` object looks like this, (Pay attention on lo & hi variables, those are objects of class `Routeguide::Point`)

```
<Routeguide::Rectangle: lo: <Routeguide::Point: latitude: 400000000, longitude: -750000000>, hi: <Routeguide::Point: latitude: 420000000, longitude: -730000000>>`
```

I have correct json string for this object,

```
json_string = '{"lo":{"latitude":400000000,"longitude":-750000000},"hi":{"latitude":420000000,"longitude":-730000000}}'
```

I need to parse this json string again to create `Routeguide::Rectangle` class object like:

```
<Routeguide::Rectangle: lo: <Routeguide::Point: latitude: 400000000, longitude: -750000000>, hi: <Routeguide::Point: latitude: 420000000, longitude: -730000000>>`
```

I am using below code to achieve this:

```
JSON.parse(json_string, object_class: Routeguide::Rectangle)
```

But that is giving me error on JSON.parse method:
`#<ArgumentError: Unknown field: latitude>`

Stacktrace:

```
[
  "/Users/psen/.rbenv/versions/2.7.7/lib/ruby/2.7.0/json/common.rb:156:in `[]='",
  "/Users/psen/.rbenv/versions/2.7.7/lib/ruby/2.7.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse'",
  "/Users/psen/.rbenv/versions/2.7.7/lib/ruby/2.7.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse'"
]
```

Comment: `object_class` sets the class which will be used for _all_ JSON objects. However, not all your JSON objects do represent `Routeguide::Rectangle` instances. Some represent `Routeguide::Point` instances which have different attributes, hence the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're also generating that json string, you could look into using [JSON Additions](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.2/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#module-JSON-label-JSON+Additions). You'd have to define a [Custom Addition](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.2/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#module-JSON-label-Custom+JSON+Additions) to help with the serialization & deserialization.

Comment: Thanks for response, but I don't think this could solve my problem completely because `Routeguide::Rectangle` class is not fixed for me and there could be any class. Basically I will know the class at runtime only and hence I don't think json addition will help in any way. any further comments? @goalaleo